# enviroment variable is in ~/bash_profile but wont show up in printenv

Tags: bash, macos, ubuntu

I am trying to add an enviroment variable for ANDROID_HOME like so:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

then I add a new line with the content:

```
ANDROID_HOME="~/Library/Android/sdk"
```

then I proceed to save the file and check `printenv` to list all enviroment variables and ANDROID_HOME doesn't show up. Why's that?

Comment: You need to source `~/.bash_profile` and keep `~` outside quotes

Comment: What do you mean by I need to source it? :) Would you provide me an example ?

Comment: Run `source ~/.bash_profile` from shell prompt

Comment: Great thanks ! Now its in the list. And now the variable needs to be ANDROID_HOME=~"/Library/Android/sdk" ?